# How to make lightdm more stable on boot?

Tags: boot, greeter, release-odin

I'm really enjoying ElementaryOS Odin so far; my only major complaint is that `lightdm` is quite unstable on boot.

Specifically on probably 75% of hard boots I do, it either fails to initialise or crashes shortly after initialisation. I'm usually either presented with my motherboard's logo, or else I see a brief flash of Greeter followed by a crash to black or the board logo screen again.

TTY can be enabled from this screen with CTRL+ALT+F2 as usual, and usually some combination of repeating `sudo service lightdm restart` and `sudo reboot now` will eventually land me on Greeter in a stable state, but it's inconsistent and just stresses me out.

Is there anything I can tweak or investigate to try to achieve better stability? I usually keep my graphics drivers up-to-date and updating them hasn't fixed this in the past so I doubt it's related.

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/syslog` around the time of a LightDM crash that might point to the issue? Are you using a system with dedicated or integrated graphics? How much RAM is installed? Generally when I see LightDM crash it's either a custom configuration error or a lack of available memory 

Comment: I had a look and I get the following repeated a lot (My guess is that this is either me restarting it or an autoretry):
`lightdm[1190]: Seat type 'xlocal' is deprecated, use 'type=local' instead`
`systemd[1]: Started Session c1 of user lightdm.`
`systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`
`systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`
`systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.`
None of the surrounding logs give any indication of what this relates to by the looks.

Comment: So It happened again on my next boot and I took another look, specifically running lightdm in debug mode with `sudo lightdm --test-mode --debug` under TTY and capturing the output from stderr. [This log file](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b75Y) is the result. 
I believe the offending line is: `[+1.05s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel` ; is there some log I can look at for the greeter's behaviour? Given that I'm using the elementary greeter, I don't know if it's a bug or something specific to my system

Comment: Do you have a `/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log` file? If so, it may contain some of the specifics behind the error. The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is a permissions issue but, if this is an intermittent problem, it’s likely not permissions. Do you have multiple OSes installed on the machine and switch between them? 

Comment: I have such a file but it looks like it includes the same startup header repeated over and over so it's not much help. `cat x-0.log | grep lightdm` yields nothing. It points me to a different logfile, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` which also doesn't have any lines referencing lightdm. I use only elementaryos with dedicated graphics (3060TI) and 16Gb of RAM.

Comment: Hmm ... this might be a bug that needs attention from a developer, then. Could you [report the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues) with as much detail as possible? I'm not an Elementary developer, so don't have the necessary knowledge of Light DM to begin offering a solution 